# how to execute a vba macro every 30 minutes automatically?

Tags: java, excel, vba

I'm working on a project to send alert notifications to a mailing list. I've an excel file with a vba macro that permit its updating from a datatbase. I need to execute the macro in the file automatically every 30 minutes without having to open the file.
i've been told to write this macro in a separate program, but i don't know how to do it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Excel VBA DOM has a nice feature called `Application.OnTime`. This can schedule a macro to run at any time. To run a Macro every 15 min, just schedule for 15 min in the future on application startup, and then schedule 15 min in the future everytime the macro runs.

From this website: http://www.ozgrid.com/Excel/run-macro-on-time.htm

Example:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
  Application.OnTime Now + TimeValue("00:15:00"), "MyMacro"
End Sub
```

Comment: thanks for the link.
but how can i execute the macro without having to open the file? is it possible?

Comment: And it's not possible to update a macro without opening a file because the macro is stored inside your file.

Otherwise you will have to write your macro as a separate program, in which case you could use Windows scheduler to run it periodically.

Comment: @ McNabb it seems exactly what i need. how can i do this?

Comment: how can i write the macro in a separate program? i've never worked with vba so i've no idea about this

Comment: If you absolutely have to have the macro run from within Excel, you could write a simple batch file (Google ".bat batch files") to launch Excel and use Windows Scheduler to run the batch file.  Put the code for your macro to run using the Launch/Open event.  That way the code will be run when the work book is opened, the workbook is opened by a batch file, the batch file is run by Windows Scheduler.

You could also look into VBScript or perhaps what you need to do can be done by a batch file.